# Password field in DB changes to 0

Tags: php, passwords

This code doesn't change the password for the signed in user, instead it changes to 0 and then doesn't allow me to sign back in. I understand md5 is not the securest and because this isn't going to be a active site just for a project. However, I'm open to suggestions about an alternative. I have two fields in the db called password and password2 which need to be both changed once they change their password. Also, the error messages don't show up.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
       header("Location: sign_up.php");
    } else {
          $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
    }

    include ("connect.php");


    ?>

    <?php

    //Variables

    if(isset($_POST['change_pass_submit'])){

    $oldpassword = $_POST['oldpassword'];
    $newpassword1 = $_POST['newpassword1'];
    $newpassword2 = $_POST['newpassword2'];




        $pass_query  = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$username'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pass_query)) {

            $existing_pass = $row ['password'];


            //Checking if md5 encrypted password matches
            $md5_oldpassword = md5($oldpassword);
            //check if the old password and the old password entered now match
            if ($md5_oldpassword == $existing_pass){
                //check if the two new passwords match 
                if ($newpassword1 == $newpassword2) {

                    $md5_newpassword = md5($newpassword1);
                    $md5_newpassword2 = md5($newpassword2);
                    //Query to update the password
                    $password_update_query = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE users SET password='$md5_newpassword' AND password2='$md5_newpassword2' WHERE email='$username'");

                    echo "Your password has now changed!";

                    }
                    else{

                        echo "Your new password and re entered password does not match. Please try again.";
                        }
                }
                else {
                    echo "Your old password does not match. Please try again.";
                    }
            }

        }


    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <h3> Change your Password: </h3>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="oldpassword">Old Password:</label>
          <input type="oldpassword" class="form-control" name="oldpassword" placeholder="Enter old password" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="newpassword1">New Password:</label>
          <input type="newpassword1" class="form-control" name="newpassword1" placeholder="Enter new password" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="newpassword2">New Password:</label>
          <input type="newpassword2" class="form-control" name="newpassword2" placeholder="Re-Enter new password" >
        </div>
         <center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="change_pass_submit" style=" background-color:#337AB7; color:white;">Change Password</button>
        </center>

     </form>
     </div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you store the same value *twice* in the table?

Comment: ...and why MD5? Have you watched *"Back to the Future"* one too many times?

Comment: @David its for verification when the user registers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i guess so..what would you recommend?

Comment: @N.Singh: That's why a user *enters* a password twice.  But you don't need to *save* it twice.  The code explicitly checks if the two values are equal before storing them both, so you already *know* that the two values are equal.  When would you ever need to retroactively check that again?

Comment: PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
 Or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/ and a prepared statement. Don't go live with this. @N.Singh

Comment: @David yes you have a point so if i take that out how do i make this code work so that it changes the password.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you, i will consider this. As stated above i won't be going live with this system just on my local network.

Comment: @N.Singh: I guess first you'll need to debug this to find out where it's failing.  You claimed that the field is being updated with a value of `0`.  So is `$md5_newpassword` also `0`?  Is `$newpassword1` also `0`?  At what point does the initial problem occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your query:

```
"UPDATE users SET password='$md5_newpassword' AND password2='$md5_newpassword2' WHERE email='$username'"
```

It should be:

```
"UPDATE users SET password='$md5_newpassword', password2='$md5_newpassword2' WHERE email='$username'"
```

However, the error in your query is **NOT** the big issue here. The BIG issue is that your code is *EXTREMELY INSECURE*:

1. It is vulnerable to [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection):
   *anyone* with malicious intend could do *anything they like* with your database. You should start using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) (take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) in PHP).
2. Your passwords are not properly hashed!
   Use PHP's build in functions: [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead of `md5` (The `md5` hashing algorithm is old. Several issues with it have been identified. For password hashing, the issue is that it is designed to be *fast*. Fast means it is [easy to crack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43683/is-it-possible-to-brute-force-all-8-character-passwords-in-an-offline-attack). Fast means specialized hardware can do [350 billion guesses per second](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/)).